# images overlap for masonry and google map not taking up width of division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically, I made a simple website.

I am using bootstrap along with masonry jquery and google maps.

This is the basic page of my website.
[image]

How this website works is like when gallery is click, index page will fadeout and gallery page is faded in.

Lets go straight to the point which is my CSS. I am wondering what is wrong with it since I am encountering this problem.

My masonry images for gallery will overlap each other but if I place things out of the division class section. Everything is fine. Same goes for the google map width problem.

Things will only be ok after the window is resized manually.

Here are the SS for the problems
[image]
[image]

my entire css link
http://pastebin.com/kqWaszqF
my custom js link
http://pastebin.com/uqSvaMeT
my index page link
http://pastebin.com/eKHyJV95

As you can see, if I place all this codes for gallery and map outside of  everything will be working fine and great but if I put it inside of that . This the above problem happens.

I tried everything like min-width: 100%, width: 100% or whatsoever. Seems like this problem always exist. Even if I setTimeOut to my javascript for masonry and googlemap, it works sometimes but not perfect as it also fails.

Can some kind soul please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a fiddle with html so i can test it in order to help you.